# Calling method of Fragment from MainActivity using interface, NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to do these **steps(are given below)**  to call fragment methods in my activity without any fragment id and tags. but im getting NullpointerException . This is very important for me to work this out... are these right steps call fragment method from activity?  **if YES**  , am i  doing it right?? **if NO** , is there any better way to call the fragment method from my activity??   AND my MainActivty and Fragmet Given below...    plz help ,thanks

*_STEPS_WHICH_I_AM_TRYING_TO_DO*

> 1 STEP)First create an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void myAction() ;
}
```

Your fragment must implement this interface.

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface
```

> 2 STEP)  In your activity, define a field of type MyInterface :

```
 private MyInterface listener ;

 public void setListener(MyInterface listener) {
   this.listener = listener ;
}
```

> 3 STEP)When creating your fragment and adding it :

```
setListener(myFragment);
```

Finally, when the condtion happens that you want to call the Fragment method,        just call:

```
   listener.myAction() ; // this will call the implementation in your   MyFragment class
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{ 

 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
private hell listener;
   ClaimFragment claimFragment;
    setListener(claimFragment);
     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            listener.willwork();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
    });
}
       tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

  //THIS IS MY INTERFACE IN MAINACTIVITY

public interface hell {
    void willwork();
}

public void setListener(hell listener) {
   this.listener = listener ;
}
```

*ClaimFragment.java*

```
public class ClaimFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener , MainActivity.hell {

    @Override
    public void willwork() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this is ClaimFrag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

*MY_LOG*

```
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: earn.free.,        PID: 20843
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void                earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivity$hell.willwork()' on a null object reference
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   earn.free.cashback.snapcash.MainActivity$2.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:152)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at       android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1856)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:625)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at      android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:609)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSele cted(TabLayout.java:2008)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1025)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:995)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1272)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1377 )
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at        android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-06 18:31:23.104 20843-20843/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-06 18:31:23.105 747-1255/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing  activity 1 earn.free.cashback.snapcash/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Your code is a real mess, im seeing 2 interfaces where you should only have one. But you only use the 'hell' interface, but where is the 'hell' field defined? where are you storing the fragment reference?

Comment: i thought , put that code which im trying to implemt for ease to understand for others, if u want i can put all my code?

Comment: What is `claimFragment` in `MainActivity`? It appears from nowhere (as does `viewPager`).

Comment: fragment reference??

Comment: this my fragment (ClaimFragment)where im implemention my method

Comment: Where it `claimFragment` declared though, and where is a reference assigned to it? I'd expect to see something like `ClaimFragment claimFragment = **Something (ClaimFragment.newInstance(), new ClaimFragment(), etc.**`.

Comment: @Nanac yeah its a mess , u have any idea why its not wprking

Comment: @PPartisan  (ClaimFragment.newInstance(), new ClaimFragment()  ?? no  i didnt do this in my mainActiviy.java

Comment: You never initialise `claimFragment`, you only declare it.Therefore, it will be `null` when you try to use it inside `setListener()`, hence the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108419/discussion-between-sandeep-singh-and-ppartisan).